# Strange characters only in some entries

Tags: wordpress

In a wordpress website has appeared only a few entries with the problem of the strange characters in letters with accent mark or the ñ letter.

I've found one solution that proposed change in wp-config.php

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

for

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf-8');
```

but this solutions doesn't work.

The question is that the pages with the problem (only the content, not the titles, menu...) are seeing correctly in the backend.

I've tried other solutions proposed here https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107096/problema-con-s%C3%ADmbolos-extra%C3%B1os-en-tildes-%C3%B1-y-s%C3%B3lo-en-algunas-p%C3%A1ginas but none of them works.

Any idea?

Comment: Is it after migration? If you open a page in the editor in the backend and save it again does it help?

Comment: What's the Content-Type that is being sent? Menus etc might escape special chars in their content , e.g. `&ntilde;` instead of `ñ`.

Comment: The problem appeared without a migration. Maybe an update but I'm not sure. Make a change and save doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The problem only appear in the content of the page, not in the rest of the page (menus, widgets...) and only in the frontend.